# do i need to paginate data in ms access with a sql command?

Tags: php, ms-access, pagination, odbc

As there is no native offset function in ms access, I am using following technique to paginate data taken from this tutorial:http://www.jertix.org/en/blog/programming/implementation-of-sql-pagination-with-ms-access.html

```
 Select TOP Row_Per_Page * From [
    Select TOP (TotRows - ((Page_Number - 1) * Row_Per_Page) 
    From SampleTable Order By ColumnName DESC
 ] Order By ColumnName ASC

 --Page 1
 SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [SELECT TOP 17 * FROM SampleTable ORDER BY ID DESC; ]. 
 AS t1 ORDER BY ID;

 --Page 2 
 SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [SELECT TOP 13 * FROM SampleTable ORDER BY ID DESC; ]. 
 AS t1 ORDER BY ID;

 --Page 3 
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [SELECT TOP  9 * FROM SampleTable ORDER BY ID DESC; ]. 
AS t1 ORDER BY ID;

 --Page 4  
 SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [SELECT TOP  5 * FROM SampleTable ORDER BY ID DESC; ]. 
 AS t1 ORDER BY ID;

 --Page 5  
 SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [SELECT TOP  1 * FROM SampleTable ORDER BY ID DESC; ]. 
 AS t1 ORDER BY ID;
```

With this technique, for page one, the database has to select all the records inside subquery. Is this technique as efficient as mysql offset and limit. If not I do not think, pagination is at all necessary on the sql side. I could just use some client side pagination probably with some javascript. Is there a better way to paginate in ms access or am I better off without pagination as there is no real advantage over performance?

Comment: As so often it seems: It depends. As you have the php tag in your question I assume it is a web application: obviously if you have thousands of records over a slow connection pagination would massively improve the performance of your application. But if not, and if the datasets are relatively small the usability is better when you have everything in the memory than when every page has to be fetched from the server.

Comment: I get the advantage of using pagination and i use it for mysql database since it has native support for it. But access db does not have native support for offset.  So using top keyword the database has to fetch all the all the records in the subquery. I m using pagination on the Client side using javascript.

Comment: My point is: when you ask: should I use pagination on the server side even when it is relatelively slow because it has to fetch all those records - you at least have to add how many dataset we speak about. With thousands of records that contain hundreds of HD-pictures each, I'd say server-side pagination is much cheaper. With the 20 records you show in your sample client-side is better and easier to use. What's in your db?

Comment: It is a growing dataset and will get larger. Mysql will only read the rows from the point of offset but in access db for page 1 query the sub query has to read all the records and then the outer query limits the number of records. So i dont see any advantage in case of access database since it has to go through all the record set. I m speaking of query optimization. With or without pagination query all the rows has to be read